# Combobox with comparison operators

Tags: vb6, combobox, comparison, operators, equation

I have an equation evaluator I need to make in Visual Basic.

For example, for the following equation the answer would be true.

```
(12 = 12) AND (12 > 1)
   true   and   true
```

For both comparison operators I've created a combo box to insert <, >, =, <=, >=, <>.

My problem is, I don't know how to access the combo box to get the right operator to evaluate the equation. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Sorry, cannot really tell what your question is.  I get that you are trying to construct an formula, but exactly what part you need help with is not clear.  Perhaps you could show us what you have so far, and then point out where in that code you need help?

Comment: The question is unclear, that's for sure.  The only reason I understood it is because I had to implement something very similar a couple of years ago.

Comment: I've done them too, but there are a lot of nouns and verbs missing in this question.  I'd definitely need psychic powers to figure out what's being asked for.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is that you should create a SELECT CASE statement where you evaluate every possible combobox combination and build your formula based on that.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to [Evaluate your VB expression at runtime](http://www.devx.com/vb2themax/Tip/18773), the suggested link shows you how. 
For a more.. .NET solution, [check this article](http://www.giuseppeporcelli.com/post/2008/08/22/An-Expression-Evaluator-inside-the-NET-Framework.aspx): it shows you how to take advantage from the Compute method within a DataTable to evaluate simple expressions. It also lists an [MSDN link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumn.expression.aspx) to all available operations.

HTH,
mt

Answer (score 0):

I think you could do it using string types...

```
if string.format("{0}{1}{2}",cbox1.text,cbox2.text,cbox3.text)=true then

end if
```

I dont have a compiler on my home computer but I think that would work for you. I do something similar with radio buttons, but its a full string comparison...